# EXCEL COUNTIFS Not calculating comparison properly - returns 0

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Hi I have the following table and am using the COUNTIFS function to calculate the values.

```
      B    C

6   (0)     (-0.55)

7   (0)     (0.45)

8   (-0.55) (10)

9   (-0.5)  (5)

10  (-0.45) (4)

11  (-0.4)  (3)

12  (-0.35) (5)
```

When I use the following formula the calculation works

```
=COUNTIFS(B8:B12,">-55%")
```

When I use the following formula the equation returns 0

```
=COUNTIFS(B8:B12,">C6")
```

Can someone explain why this returns 0 and how to fix it?

Answer (score 3):

If you are using a cell reference with `COUNTIF(S)`, `SUMIF(S)`, etc., you need the operator in quotation marks, then an ampersand, then the cell reference. With `">C6"`, `C6` is no longer a cell reference, but the string literal (text) "C6".

```
=COUNTIFS(B8:B12,">"&C6)
```

See the [`COUNTIFS` function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/countifs-function-dda3dc6e-f74e-4aee-88bc-aa8c2a866842) for more detail - note that in this case, while `COUNTIFS` works perfectly fine, you only need `COUNTIF` for one criterion.